# Creating Multiple Virtual Sites on a WAMP

Tags: apache, virtual, localhost, wampserver

I'm trying to host multiple sites on my Wamp server (Windows),

I have added new virtual hosts in "C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 bitrix
```

I created a new folder "C:\wamp\bitrix" to serve my second project's files.
And than add this code in httpd.conf:

```
    NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www'
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName bitrix
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\bitrix'
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i'm trying to access http://localhost or http://bitrix i'm getting "403 Forbidden" error.

If someone knows where is my mistake please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put them both under a different folder of the htdocs directory?

MAMP -> htdocs

Comment: no i'm creating a project that needs to be separated from wamp's default www folder